# how to bind a field to an lwc component

Tags: api

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

hi guys i am recently learning salesforce and lwc, how do i link my subject  email template to lwc component?

Comment: Can you edit your question to elaborate a little more on the use case you are trying to achieve? "binding an email template subject to an lwc component" isn't really a thing, so we'll need a little more info on what you are trying to achieve to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

**In your case you can do this type of binding.
There are both ways, either you can query or the way i have done below, whichever suits the scenario.**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi'

const fields = [
    'Opportunity.Invoice_Number__c'
];

export default class Record extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields 
     [OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD] }) invoiceNumber;

   get invoiceNumberData() {
    return this.invoiceNumber.data.fields.Invoice_Number__c.value;
    }

}
```

```
<lightning-output-field value={invoiceNumberData} label="Invoice Number" ></lightning-output-field>
```

Comment: gives an error message :  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields 
     [OPPORTUNITY_NAME_FIELD] }) invoiceNumber;

Comment: I need to insert a sequence number (opportunity.invoice_number__c) into my lwc component, I created it at opportunity and I have it in my email template

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kuz and welcome to Stack Exchange.

You can bind properties in your JS file to your HTML file by wrapping them in {}.

Our HTML file binds to the expression {greeting} from our JS file.

```
    <div>
            hello the greeting is {greeting}
  </div>        
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
 greeting = 'Hello World'

}
```

Comment: hi brooks, i need to link subject email template to lwc component